# powershell -ilike operations too similar

Tags: powershell

is there a way to say, that between a `*` there is only a numeric value of maybe two values.
i want to select items, but the way i can differentiate them is very limited.

i want to store values like "31.04.2003" with following line of code:
`$contentDateReal = $content_ -ilike '*"*.*.*",'`

this works for me, in the most times but, sometimes i got values like: "Installation Acrobat Reader 10.0.1 "

those one also fit the -ilike filter but i dont want them. is there a way to say, that i only want values that contains numbers, and that before the first dot, there is only 2 ("xx") index sizes, after the first dot also ("xx"), and after the second one there is space for four index values like "xxxx" or "2020".

Answer (score 2):

While, you can use character ranges such as `[0-9]` to match a character (digit) in that range, PowerShell's [wildcard expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) do not support matching a *varying number* of these characters.

That is, `'10' -like '[0-9][0-9]'` is `$true`, but `'2' -like '[0-9][0-9]'`  is not.

<sup>Note: `-ilike` is just an alias for `-like`, which is case-*insensitive* by default, as all PowerShell operators are; conversely, use `-clike` for case-*sensitive* matching. This naming convention applies to all operators that (also) process text.</sup>

While you do want to match *fixed* numbers of digits, matching with a fixed number of `[0-9]` ranges  may still yield false positives if *additional* digits are present at the start or at the end, so to rule these out you need to use the more sophisticated matching that [*regular expressions*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) (regexes) provide:

PowerShell supports regexes via the [`-match` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match) (among others), so you could use the following:

```
('Some Software 31.04.2003', 'Installation Acrobat Reader 10.0.1').ForEach({
   if ($_ -match '\b(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})\b') {
     "'$_' matched; extracted version number: $($Matches[1])"
   }
})
```

The above yields the following, because only the first string matched:

```
'Some Software 31.04.2003' matched; extracted version number: 31.04.2003
```

Explanation of the regex:

- `\b` matches at word boundaries, which means that something other than word character (a letter, a digit, or `_`) must occur at that position (which can include the start and end of the string).
- `\d` matches a digit (roughly equivalent to `[0-9]`, the latter limiting matching to the decimal digits in the ASCII sub-range of Unicode); `{2}`, for instance, stipulates that exactly *2* instances of digits must be present.
- `\.` represents a verbatim `.` (it must be `\`-escaped, because `.` is a regex metacharacter representing *any* character).
- Enclosing a subexpression in `(...)` creates a so-called *capture group*, which additionally captures what the subexpression matched, and makes that available starting with index `1` (for the *first* of potentially multiple (unnamed) capture groups) in the [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches) variable.

Note that `-match` - unlike [`-like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-like) - matches *substrings* by default, so there's no need to also match what comes before or after the version number.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being late, but this one is one of the first results in the search engines and the answer given is at least incomplete.

This situation should be solved with regex matching. This way you can implement all the search logic you do manually in a single regular expression. This way you also can take into consideration where in the line the date is located at (beginning, end, in between some other text, ...)

To match a date like `31.04.2003` you could use this regex: `'\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}'`

The regex means:

- One to two `{1,2}` numerical `\d` chars followed by ...
- a dot `\.` (escaped because `.` in regex means *'one of any but whitespace'* followed by ...
- one or two numerical chars followed by ...
- a dot followed by ...
- four {4} numerical chars.

Example:

```
PS C:\Users\any> "10.2.2001" -cmatch '\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}'
True
PS C:\Users\any> "10.0.1" -cmatch '\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}'
False
```

Please also note:

- `-like` is for wildcard comparison
- `-match` is for regex matching
- `-clike` is for case sensitive wildcard comparison
- `-cmatch` is for case sensitive regex matching.